# Reading TH1D and TH2D histograms in uproot

Tags: python, matplotlib, uproot

I have a file in cern root format which contains a number of TH1D and TH2D histograms. I'd like to be able to plot these by using uproot4 to read them, then matplotlib to do the plotting.
I can open the file with uproot.open(path) ok, and print(file.keys()) gives a list of the histogram names, but I can't list the histogram contents or convert them to any other meaningful forms.
Can anyone point me to example code?

Answer (score 1):

Following [this section of the tutorial](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic.html#extracting-histograms-from-a-file), particularly the end, you can do:

```py
import uproot
file = uproot.open("https://scikit-hep.org/uproot3/examples/hepdata-example.root")
file["hpxpy"].to_hist().plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The `to_hist()` part sends the histogram to the hist library (which must be installed). The hist documentation has sections on [installation](https://hist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) and [plotting](https://hist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/notebooks/Plots.html).

Comment: Thanks. That with mplhep has got me working.

Comment: I am curious how you can work with THnSparse instead. It has got my head scratching and I cannot seem to find anything in Uproot for THnSparse.

Comment: There isn't anything in Uproot for THnSparse, which is not a subclass of TH1. There _might_ be enough implemented to read a THnSparse object in Uproot without any convenience methods, which would make it usable but all of the functionality would be hidden in its `all_members` dict. If that's the case, then we should add a [behavior](https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot5/tree/main/src/uproot/behaviors) for THnSparse to make it convenient to work with, or at least convert to sparse [hist](https://hist.readthedocs.io/) objects.